# How to fill report using JSON datasource without getting null values?

Tags: java, json, jasper-reports

I'm using Jasper Reports to build a simple report pdf. I have a JSON file that looks like this:

```
{"employees": [
    {"firstName" : "John", "lastName" : "Doe"},
    {"firstName" : "Anna", "lastName" : "Smith"},
    {"firstName" : "Peter", "lastName" : "Jones"}
]}
```

And I'm trying to read it in like this:

```
File file = new File("E:/Workspaces/jasperPDFreport/src/main/resources/emp.json");
JsonDataSource datasource = new JsonDataSource(file);

JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load("E:/Workspaces/jasperPDFreport/src/main/resources/jsonTemplate.jrxml");
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
Map parameters = new HashMap();
JasperPrint jasperPrint;
jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, datasource);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "BasicReport.pdf");
JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);
```

However my the values from the JSON file are not passed to my pdf.

This is my Template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.1.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.1.1  -->
<!-- 2015-10-22T13:45:32 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4_2" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="9e494ebe-c1fb-4448-bcee-38994e9720f7">
    <!--property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.source" value="emp.json"/-->
    <queryString language="json">
        <![CDATA[employees]]>
    </queryString>  
    <field name="firstName" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[firstName]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="lastName" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[lastName]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="02b279da-3795-4655-8571-5a36a3ef378c"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{firstName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="671e61ad-8d8f-48cb-969f-78c05a516398"/>
                <text><![CDATA[firstName]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="30" width="100" height="30" uuid="9d53f46f-a252-48b3-9213-8c3092c29f49"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{lastName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="100" height="30" uuid="3b49affb-685a-4df2-a872-c0e6fdcab94b"/>
                <text><![CDATA[lastName]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Now you see the commented out line

> property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.source" value="emp.json"

If I comment this in, everything works as intended, I don't want to hard code my JSON values into the template, because later on I want to get them from a rest service, that's not ready yet. I do not understand, why the values are not getting parsed into the report, instead i just get two null values.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [JasperReports - JSON Data Source Sample (version 6.4.3)](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jsondatasource/)

> The built-in JSON query executer (see the JsonQueryExecuter class) is a tool that uses the query string to produce a JsonDataSource instance, based on specific built-in parameters (or equivalent report properties). This query executer is registered via JsonQueryExecuterFactory factory class. 
>   In order to prepare the data source, the JSON query executer looks for the JSON_INPUT_STREAM parameter that contains the JSON source objects in the form of an java.io.InputStream. If no JSON_INPUT_STREAM parameter is provided, then the query executer looks for the alternate net.sf.jasperreports.json.source String parameter or report property that stores the path to the location of the JSON source file. 
>   JsonQueryExecuter runs the query over the input source and stores the result in an in-memory JsonDataSource object.

So if you do not want to use:

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.source" value="emp.json"/>
```

You need to pass the file as `java.io.InputStream` in the parameter `JSON_INPUT_STREAM`

Hence you are currently passing it as datasource you should try something like this

```
params.put(JsonQueryExecuterFactory.JSON_INPUT_STREAM, new FileInputStream(file));
JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(jasperReport, params);
```

If you instead like to use the new `JsonQLQueryExecuterFactory`  [JSONQL Data Source](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jsonqldatasource/index.htm)

```
params.put(JsonQLQueryExecuterFactory.JSON_INPUT_STREAM, new FileInputStream(file));
JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(jasperReport, params);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you pass your json string as InputStream then it will works.

```
String reportContents = "{}" //your json
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(reportContent.getBytes());
Map params = new HashMap();
params.put(JsonQueryExecuterFactory.JSON_INPUT_STREAM, is);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRBeanCollectionDataSource.html) for data source implementation that wraps a collection of JavaBean objects.

```
List<YourClass> yourBeanCollection = queryDataFromJSON();

JRDataSource beanCollectionDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(yourBeanCollection);

JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,
                reportParams, beanCollectionDataSource);
```

and in the report template import java.util and declare the collection which you "injected" in the report

```
<import value="java.util.*"/>
<field name="yourBeanCollection" class="java.util.List"/>
```

also take a look [here](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/534582/how-put-list-java-report) for an example