# JasperPrint create output with json datasource - queryString example

Tags: java, json, jasper-reports

JSON Data

```
{
   "TABLE":[
               {
                 "CUSTOMER_IBAN": "TR29705372138488430000",
                 "CUSTOMERADDRESS": "Kocaeli",
                 "CUSTOMERSURNAME": "Kahveci",
                 "CUSTOMERNR": "5798186825",
                 "CUSTOMERNAME": "Cemile",
                 "CUSTOMERACCOUNT": "4051956-9233"
               },
               {
                 "CUSTOMER_IBAN": "TR29705372138488430000",
                 "CUSTOMERADDRESS": "Kocaeli",
                 "CUSTOMERSURNAME": "Kahveci",
                 "CUSTOMERNR": "5798186825",
                 "CUSTOMERNAME": "Cemile",
                 "CUSTOMERACCOUNT": "4051956-9233"
               }
           ]
}
```

JRXML

```
    <queryString language="json">
        <![CDATA[TABLE]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="CUSTOMER_IBAN" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="CUSTOMERADDRESS" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="CUSTOMERSURNAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="CUSTOMERNR" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="CUSTOMERACCOUNT" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="CUSTOMERNAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

I use these fields in detail band for a simple table view.

I try jaspersoft studio with defining this data via DataAdapter and I get the correct output.

But when created the output with jasperPrint with below code, Exports report without detail band. It only puts a single row with all null values.

Java JasperPrint Code

```
String jsonString = JsonSerializer.serialize(dataMap);
ReportLog.print(jsonString);
JsonDataSource dataSource = new JsonDataSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(jsonString.getBytes()));
print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperTemplate, parameters, dataSource);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the JSON query string on your JsonDataSource:

```
JsonDataSource dataSource = new JsonDataSource(jsonString);
dataSource.setJsonQueryExecuterFactory(JSONQueryExecuterFactory.getInstance());
dataSource.setQueryString("TABLE");
```

Without setting the query string, the JsonDataSource assumes a single root object and treats your JSON as a single row with TABLE as a field.
You can also set the query string in the report template as you have, but it will be ignored when filling via the API if you don't also set it on the data source.
Note that the JSON query language is deprecated as of JasperReports 6.2. You should consider switching to JSONQL instead.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to implement an exporter factory based on Jasper for our framework, so I need to query this data in jasper file. I have only two component, JSON data and .jasper file. TABLE keyword can be anything in my scenario. Can there be any workaround for this issue?

Comment: Also there is no method called setQueryString or setJsonQueryExecuterFactory in JsonDataSource under net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data?  I'm using jasperreports 6.2

Comment: This is a known limitation with the JSON query executer in JasperReports. The JSON query must match a field name in the JSON data.

To get around this, you'll need to do one of a few things:

Rename the JSON field to match the query
Use a custom JSONQL query to reference the field by path (i.e. $.TABLE[0].CUSTOMER_IBAN)
Implement a custom JsonQueryExecuterFactory that allows using a custom query language
Use a different JSON datasource implementation (like JRJsonDataSource) that doesn't require a query

Comment: According to this question, I need to pass datasource as a parameter with a stream. With this JsonQueryExecuterFactory runs query strings.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33300592/how-to-fill-report-using-json-datasource-without-getting-null-values